# Use of PEM format in RSA

Tags: rsa, pem, pkcs#11, der

What is the use of PEM format of the RSA key? Is there any specific reason why the PEM format was introduced in RSA?

Note: My understanding is PEM format is the base 64 encoded values.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for programming questions, not just any question that pops up during your work. The history of PEM format is certainly off-topic here.

Comment: I tried searching the web but couldn't get the convincing answer. If you have any link or detail regarding it, please help me by sharing it.

Comment: Better ask it at https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks for guidance.